# Pandas: Discard rows previous to value including value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to discard every row previous to where `Time` is `0` containing the same `ID` as the row with the `0`-value. The row containing `0` shall also be deleted.

The data is as follows:

```
                          Time  Author         ID
Date
2018-04-23 08:09:52.558    60  1744025         44
2018-04-23 14:26:12.294   360  1244021         10
2018-04-23 15:19:47.667    45  1244021         10
2018-04-23 18:05:25.417   240  1249997         19
2018-04-23 18:58:20.776   180  2185555         19
2018-04-23 18:59:50.883   120  2185555         19
2018-04-23 19:29:30.500   300  1686620         19
2018-04-24 00:23:45.673     0  1249997         19
2018-04-24 06:55:29.529    10  1244021         10
2018-04-24 14:08:19.080   270  1686620         19
2018-04-24 17:58:30.757   120  1416825         39
2018-04-24 19:33:41.127   600  1249997         19
```

I want it to be:

```
                          Time  Author         ID
Date
2018-04-23 08:09:52.558    60  1744025         44
2018-04-23 14:26:12.294   360  1244021         10
2018-04-23 15:19:47.667    45  1244021         10
2018-04-24 06:55:29.529    10  1244021         10
2018-04-24 14:08:19.080   270  1686620         19
2018-04-24 17:58:30.757   120  1416825         39
2018-04-24 19:33:41.127   600  1249997         19
```

I fiddled around with `idxmax()`:

```
df[(df.Time == 0).idxmax():]
```

But that does not take the `ID` into account.

So how can I do that in the most "pythonic" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` + `cumsum` trick here:

```
df[~df.Time.eq(0)[::-1].groupby(df.ID, sort=False).cumsum()]

                         Time   Author  ID
Date                                      
2018-04-23 08:09:52.558    60  1744025  44
2018-04-23 14:26:12.294   360  1244021  10
2018-04-23 15:19:47.667    45  1244021  10
2018-04-24 06:55:29.529    10  1244021  10
2018-04-24 14:08:19.080   270  1686620  19
2018-04-24 17:58:30.757   120  1416825  39
2018-04-24 19:33:41.127   600  1249997  19
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you! 
Would you explain in a few words whats going on there?

Comment: @JACKSONMEISTER What I do is figure out the first row with a 0 per group, and then use cumsum to mark every row before it for removal.